# Send listbox selected items to another listbox on a different uwp page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, listbox, listboxitem

I have a list on page one with car objects. I want to click on a car from the list and click a button which will send the selected car to a list on another uwp page.
I am trying to put the `listCar.selecteditems` in an empty list I created called `purchase` and display `purchase` on page 2. With the code I have at the moment, it is only displaying `ProjectName_Car` in the list on page 2.
Any help on displaying this properly is appreciated.

Page1.xaml.cs

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = listCars.SelectedItems.ToList().Cast<Car>();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            purchase.Add(item);
        }

        liistCar.ItemsSource = purchase;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), listCar.Items);
    }
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        lstCars.ItemsSource =  e.Parameter as List<Car> ;

    }
```

Edit: Page1.xaml

```
 <ListBox Name="listCars" ItemsSource="{x:Bind cars}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="Car">
                    <StackPanel Padding="20">
                        <Image Width="200" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{x:Bind imgCar}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind Name}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> € <Run Text="{Binding Price}" /></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one transfers your selected car list object to next page as parameter with all its properties.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="YourPage"

    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel  x:Name="Stacky" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox Name="listCars" ItemsSource="{x:Bind cars}" SelectionMode="Multiple"  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF1EFEF" Opacity="0.7" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,94,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car">
                    <StackPanel Padding="20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Image Width="200" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{x:Bind imgCar}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind name}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> € <Run Text="{x:Bind price}" /></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Done Selecting" Click="Add_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            cars.Add(new Car() { imgCar = "ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg", name = "Car1", price = "10000" });
            cars.Add(new Car() { imgCar = "ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg", name = "Car2", price = "10001" });
            cars.Add(new Car() { imgCar = "ms-appx:///Assets/3.jpg", name = "Car3", price = "10002" });
            this.InitializeComponent();    

        }
        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Car> mySelectedItems = new List<Car>();
            foreach (Car item in listCars.SelectedItems)
            {
                mySelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), mySelectedItems);
        }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string imgCar { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
    }
```

Page2.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listCars"  SelectionMode="Multiple"  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF1EFEF" Opacity="0.7" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,94,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car">
                    <StackPanel Padding="20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Image Width="200" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{x:Bind imgCar}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind name}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> € <Run Text="{x:Bind price}" /></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```
  public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var items  =   e.Parameter as List<Car>;
            listCars.ItemsSource = items;
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but in my selectedlist it still only displays the name of my solution_ Car and not the object from the list. It should display an image, the name of the car and the price of the car

Comment: For that you need to change itemtemplate  of the listview. If you need will add that too.

Comment: That would be appreciated if you could, I have edited my code above to show the listbox.itemtemplate

Comment: I have added the complete working sample and edited my answer